# include version.txt in gh-pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I am running project pages on github and add specific links for "fast access" to binaries for those who do not want to get complete sources. All works fine but there is no version information and noone can see if there is something new. So I want to add a line where actual version is displayed. Version number can be read from version.txt which is located in master branch. gh-pages do not support php so I cannot include this simple number easy. I do not want to use javascript because of not all browsers support this. Is there a simple way to display the version number which is in version.txt of master branch without editing each time gh-pages? Does gh-pages support any serverside includes?

Thanks for any idea
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

I have got a workaround: I included image from my own server, and image there is created via php from text file located on GitHub...

Andreas